# python numba.guvectorize fails: "LV: Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts"

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to figure out how to use `numba` to generate `numpy`-style ufuncs for vectorized array operations. I noticed I am having very slow performance so I tried to debug by calling the following in my code as per the [numba FAQ](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/faq.html):

```
import llvmlite.binding as llvm
llvm.set_option('', '--debug-only=loop-vectorize')
```

Apparently my loop is not being vectorized 'due to memory conflicts.'

Again from the FAQ page, I see that this occurs 'when memory access pattern is non-trivial.' I'm not clear on what this means, but the code I am trying to vectorize seems pretty trivial to me:

```
@guvectorize(['void(f4[:,:], b1[:,:], f8, f4, f4[:,:])'],
             '(n,m), (n,m), (), () -> (n,m)', cache=True)
def enforce_cutoff(img, mask, max, nodata, out):
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if mask[i,j]:
                out[i,j] = nodata
            else:
                if img[i,j]<max:
                    out[i,j] = img[i,j]
                else:
                    out[i,j] = max-0.1
```

Any clues on why this cannot be vectorized and how I could get around it would be very much appreciated. I am pretty new to numba & have no familiarity at all with LLVM so I don't understand much of this well.

The full output from LLVM is here:

```
LV: Checking a loop in "_ZN7AtmCorr18enforce_cutoff$241E5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE5ArrayIbLi2E1A7mutable7alignedEdf5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE" from enforce_cutoff
LV: Loop hints: force=? width=0 unroll=0
LV: Found a loop: B40.us
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts
LV: Not vectorizing: Cannot prove legality.

LV: Checking a loop in "__gufunc__._ZN7AtmCorr18enforce_cutoff$241E5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE5ArrayIbLi2E1A7mutable7alignedEdf5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE" from <numba.npyufunc.wrappers._GufuncWrapper object at 0x0000020A848A6438>
LV: Loop hints: force=? width=0 unroll=0
LV: Not vectorizing: Cannot prove legality.

LV: Checking a loop in "_ZN7AtmCorr18enforce_cutoff$241E5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE5ArrayIbLi2E1A7mutable7alignedEdf5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE" from <numba.npyufunc.wrappers._GufuncWrapper object at 0x0000020A848A6438>
LV: Loop hints: force=? width=0 unroll=0
LV: Found a loop: B40.us
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Did not find one integer induction var.
LV: Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts
LV: Not vectorizing: Cannot prove legality.

LV: Checking a loop in "_ZN7AtmCorr18enforce_cutoff$241E5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE5ArrayIbLi2E1A7mutable7alignedEdf5ArrayIfLi2E1A7mutable7alignedE" from <numba.npyufunc.wrappers._GufuncWrapper object at 0x0000020A848A6438>
LV: Loop hints: force=? width=0 unroll=0
LV: Found a loop: B20.us.us
LV: Found an induction variable.
LV: Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts
LV: Not vectorizing: Cannot prove legality.
```

Comment: Your access pattern is quite complicated. If you explicitly declare C-contigous arrays SIMD-vectorization is possible. `@nb.guvectorize(['void(f4[:,::1], b1[:,::1], f8, f4, f4[:,::1])'],'(n,m), (n,m), (), () -> (n,m)', cache=True)`

Comment: Thanks @max9111 that does allow for vectorization of this code. I appreciate the suggestion. I wonder if you could elaborate on what makes this complex in terms of memory access — I assume it is just because several arrays are accessed at once? I am trying to vectorize a handful of other functions as well, at least one of which is significantly more complex than this one. What constraints are there on the 'vectorizeability' of functions such as this that coordinate access of multiple arrays? Can you recommend some good resources to help me understand this better? Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to SIMD-vectorize code on non contiguous arrays it's often time for writing explicit SIMD-vectorized code using intrinsics. (Quite the same in C, or Fortran even in a lot simpler code than this) eg. : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-and-array-contiguity If it isn't guaranteed that your input arrays aren't contiguous, but usually they are, the simplest thing is usually to make them contiguous (by np.ascontiguousarray which creates a contiguous copy if the input is not C-contiguous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround would be to ensure that the arrays are C-contiguous. If they are not c-contigous they will be copied.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit(cache=True,parallel=True)
def enforce_cutoff_2(img, mask, max, nodata, out):
    #create a contigous copy if array isn't c-contiguous
    img=np.ascontiguousarray(img)
    mask=np.ascontiguousarray(mask)

    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if mask[i,j]:
                out[i,j] = nodata
            else:
                if img[i,j]<max:
                    out[i,j] = img[i,j]
                else:
                    out[i,j] = max-0.1
```

**Timings**

```
#contiguous arrays
img=np.random.rand(1000,1000).astype(np.float32)
mask=np.random.rand(1000,1000)>0.5
max=0.5
nodata=1.
out=np.empty((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),dtype=np.float32)

%timeit enforce_cutoff_2(img, mask, max, nodata, out)
#single-thread
#678 µs ± 3.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#parallel
#143 µs ± 1.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#non contigous arrays
img=np.random.rand(2000,2000).astype(np.float32)
mask=np.random.rand(2000,2000)>0.5
img=img[0:-1:2,0:-1:2]
mask=mask[0:-1:2,0:-1:2]
max=0.5
nodata=1.
out=np.empty((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),dtype=np.float32)

%timeit enforce_cutoff_2(img, mask, max, nodata, out)
#single threaded
#with contiguous copy
#1.78 ms ± 9.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#without contiguous copy
#5.76 ms ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#parallel
#with contiguous copy
#1.42 ms ± 7.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
##without contiguous copy
#1.08 ms ± 75.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```